# Multiprocessing with Multiple Functions: Need to add a function to the pool from within another function

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```
I am measuring the metrics of an encryption algorithm that I designed. I have declared 2 functions and a brief sample is as follows:
```

```
import sys, random, timeit, psutil, os, time
from multiprocessing import Process
from subprocess import check_output

pid=0

def cpuUsage():
    global running
    while pid == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    running=true
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    while running:
        print(f'PID: {pid}\t|\tCPU Usage: {p.memory_info().rss/(1024*1024)} MB')
        time.sleep(1)
def Encryption()
    global pid, running
    pid = os.getpid()
    myList=[]
    for i in range(1000):
        myList.append(random.randint(-sys.maxsize,sys.maxsize)+random.random())
    print('Now running timeit function for speed metrics.')
    p1 = Process(target=metric_collector())
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    number=1000
    unit='msec'
    setup = '''
import homomorphic,random,sys,time,os,timeit
myList={myList}

'''
    enc_code='''
for x in range(len(myList)):
    myList[x] = encryptMethod(a, b, myList[x], d)
        '''
    dec_code='''
\nfor x in range(len(myList)):
    myList[x] = decryptMethod(myList[x])
    '''
    
    time=timeit.timeit(setup=setup,
                        stmt=(enc_code+dec_code),
                        number=number)
    running=False
    print(f'''Average Time:\t\t\t {time/number*.0001} seconds 
Total time for {number} Iters:\t\t\t {time} {unit}s
Total Encrypted/Decrypted Values:\t {number*len(myList)}''')
    sys.exit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Beginning Metric Evaluation\n...\n')

    
    
    p2 = Process(target=Encryption())
    p2.start()
    
    
    p2.join()
```

I am sure there's an implementation error in my code, I'm just having trouble grabbing the PID for the encryption method and I am trying to make the overhead from other calls as minimal as possible so I can get an accurate reading of just the functionality of the methods being called by timeit. If you know a simpler implementation, please let me know. Trying to figure out how to measure all of the metrics has been killing me softly.

I've tried acquiring the pid a few different ways, but I only want to measure performance when timeit is run. Good chance I'll have to break this out separately and run it that way (instead of multiprocessing) to evaluate the function properly, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three major problems with your code.  The net result is that you are not actually doing any multiprocessing.

The first problem is here, and in a couple of other similar places:

```
p2 = Process(target=Encryption())
```

What this code passes to Process is not the function `Encryption` but the returned value from `Encryption()`.  It is exactly the same as if you had written:

```
x = Encryption()
p2 = Process(target=x)
```

What you want is this:

```
p2 = Process(target=Encryption)
```

This code tells Python to create a new Process and execute the function Encryption() in that Process.

The second problem has to do with the way Python handles memory for Processes.  Each Process lives in its own memory space.  Each Process has its own local copy of global variables, so you cannot set a global variable in one Process and have another Process be aware of this change.  There are mechanisms to handle this important situation, documented in the multiprocessing module.  See the section titled "Sharing state between processes."  The bottom line here is that you cannot simply set a global variable inside a Process and expect other Processes to see the change, as you are trying to do with `pid`.  You have to use one of the approaches described in the documentation.

The third problem is this code pattern, which occurs for both p1 and p2.

```
p2 = Process(target=Encryption)
p2.start()
p2.join()
```

This tells Python to create a Process and to start it.  Then you immediately wait for it to finish, which means that your current Process must stop at that point until the new Process is finished.  You never allow two Processes to run at once, so there is no performance benefit.  The only reason to use multiprocessing is to run two things at the same time, which you never do.  You might as well not bother with multiprocessing at all since it is only making your life more difficult.

Finally I am not sure why you have decided to try to use multiprocessing in the first place.  The functions that measure memory usage and execution time are almost certainly very fast, and I would expect them to be much faster than any method of synchronizing one Process to another.  If you're worried about errors due to the time used by the diagnostic functions themselves, I doubt that you can make things better by multiprocessing.  Why not just start with a simple program and see what results you get?